# RAM serial number

Tags: memory, bios

Should you be able to read the serial number of the RAM in your BIOS if the manufacturer has included a section for it?  I have an ASUS Prime Z270-K mother board and have nothing but zeros listed under the serial number for my RAM.  Wondering if this is normal.

Answer (score 5):

For this feature to work, all three of the below prerequisites are needed:

- The mainboard (all the way from the DIMM sockets to the software) must support it
- The DIMMs themselves must support it
- The implementation in the DIMMs must be compatible with the implementation in the mainboard

In your case, it seems like the first point is to be answered with yes, but we do not know about the latter two. You could try to find out whether other DIMMs show a serial number.

This is in any case just an inconvenience, not a problem: if your RAM works fine (e.g. according to memtest86 or Windows RAM diagnosis) you have no reliability problem.

Comment: Yes, this is just for my understanding.  The RAM works fine.  All DIMMs show a string of 0's for the S/N, so maybe the RAM is the incompatible link.

Comment: There's another possibility you've overlooked: the serial number in the SPD chip on the DIMM really is all zeroes, and the computer is reporting that correctly.

Comment: @duskwuff Which would IMHO be Nr.2  - the DIMMs not supporting it

Answer (score 1):

As addition to the first answer:

You could try to get the RAM info from within the OS.

If you're on Windows try *wmic* and *memorychip* through the Commandline.

Or use a Live Boot System like SystemRescueCd or other variation of Linux, and boot into it.

Use a GUI Tool like *lshwgtk* or bash commands to get the informations e.g.

> cat /proc/meminfo

or

> sudo dmidecode --type 17 | more

Comment: wmic etc only reads information it is given though.  If bios doesn't present information to the OS then the OS can't read it no matter what OS or command you use.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know exactly how and from where the OS or BIOS read the Ram-Specs. But it might not be a problem with the bios-ram compatibility, perhaps checking for the right Ram version to install or a BIOS Update ?

Comment: The driving force of this question is due to a malware infection that I have.  I am trying to narrow down any and all possibilities of where the malware is hiding, which is why I've posted another question in regards to the SPD data.  My honest belief is that the serial number should be present and there  may be something going on that I don't fully understand at this point, with respect to the RAM or firmware but that is only a theory.